# httpd-vhosts showing syntax error

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php

I am using the following [tutorial](https://echo.co/blog/os-x-109-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew).

However when I test my `apache` I am getting the following error:

`Syntax error on line 1 of /Users/jessmckenzie/Sites/httpd-vhosts.conf:
Invalid command 'USERHOME=$(dscl', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Line 1 relates to the following:

`USERHOME=$(dscl . -read /Users/`jessmckenzie`NFSHomeDirectory | awk -F": " '{print $2}') cat > ~/Sites/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Why am I getting this error?

**httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
USERHOME=$(dscl . -read /Users/`jessmckenzie` NFSHomeDirectory | awk -F": " '{print $2}') cat > ~/Sites/httpd-vhosts.conf
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# Set up permissions for VirtualHosts in ~/Sites
#
<Directory "${USERHOME}/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# For http://localhost in the users' Sites folder
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "${USERHOME}/Sites"
</VirtualHost>

#
# VirtualHosts
#

## Manual VirtualHost template
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#  ServerName project.dev
#  CustomLog "${USERHOME}/Sites/logs/project.dev-access_log" combined
#  ErrorLog "${USERHOME}/Sites/logs/project.dev-error_log"
#  DocumentRoot "${USERHOME}/Sites/project.dev"
#</VirtualHost>

#
# Automatic VirtualHosts
# A directory at ${USERHOME}/Sites/webroot can be accessed at http://webroot.dev
# In Drupal, uncomment the line with: RewriteBase /

# This log format will display the per-virtual-host as the first field followed by a typical log line
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combinedmassvhost

# Auto-VirtualHosts with .dev
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName dev
  ServerAlias *.dev

  CustomLog "${USERHOME}/Sites/logs/dev-access_log" combinedmassvhost
  ErrorLog "${USERHOME}/Sites/logs/dev-error_log"

  VirtualDocumentRoot ${USERHOME}/Sites/%-2+
</VirtualHost>

# Auto-VirtualHosts with xip.io
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName xip
  ServerAlias *.xip.io

  CustomLog "${USERHOME}/Sites/logs/dev-access_log" combinedmassvhost
  ErrorLog "${USERHOME}/Sites/logs/dev-error_log"

  VirtualDocumentRoot ${USERHOME}/Sites/%-7+
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

That file (above) is not the `~/Sites/httpd-vhosts.conf` file.  It is used as a script:

```
USERHOME=$(dscl . -read /Users/`whoami` NFSHomeDirectory | awk -F": " '{print $2}') cat > ~/Sites/httpd-vhosts.conf <<EOF
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

[....]

</VirtualHost>
EOF
```

You don't paste this into an editor, but paste this directly into a terminal session.

It will then figure out your home directory, and populate that into the `~/Sites/httpd-vhosts.conf` file it creates.

Delete the ~/Sites/httpd-vhosts.conf file you have now, then paste that entire section directly into a terminal session.

Alternatively, delete the first line of the file, and replace every instance of $USERHOME with your home folder.